# Best way to configure a node with NETCONF

Tags: ietf-netmod-yang, ietf-netconf

I am quite new to Yang and Netconf based configurations.

Is there any opensource visualizer or script where it takes Yang files and help me out while creating XML payload to be used by NETCONF to configure the end node ?

Currently it is painful where I need to go through Yang file and manually form the XML payload to configure the device.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You may use [pyang](https://github.com/mbj4668/pyang) and `sample-xml-skeleton` output to generate basic structure:

`pyang -f sample-xml-skeleton <yang file>`